# property injection not working, help. Unity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unity-container

I spent a few hours trying to resolve this but with no luck. I'm using unity to inject my _translation property in my SSPResourceManagerWrapper  Class which is returning back a null, instead of the translationService object.

**Registering Dependency** UIbootstrapper class gets called when the app starts to register all dependencies. And resolved when controller object is created.

```
 public class UiBootstrapper
{
    public static IUnityContainer RegisterUiComponents(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        container.RegisterType<SSPResourceManagerWrapper>();
        container.RegisterType<SSPResourceManager>();
        container.RegisterType<ITranslationService, TranslationService>();
        return container;
    }
```

_translation property returning null here. instead of translationService object

```
public class SSPResourceManager
{
    private static ITranslationService _translationService;

    private static string _languageCode =   
                 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["LanguageCode"].ToString();


    // constructor injection
    public SSPResourceManager(ITranslationService  translationService)
    {
      _translationService = translationService;
    }


    public static string SSP_Validation_Required
    {
        get
        {
            return _translationService.Read("SSP_Validation_Required", "SSP", _languageCode); 
        }
    }
}
```

Where SSPResourceManager is used

```
 public abstract class AddressVM
{

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(SSPResourceManager), ErrorMessageResourceName 
    = "SSP_Validation_Required")]

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It's always been "Trinity, help!" and not "help, Unity" B-)

Answer (score 3):

You are creating your own instance of `SSPResourceManagerWrapper` instead of resolving it using the Unity container:

```
private static ITranslationService _translationService = 
                    new  SSPResourceManagerWrapper()._translation;
```

The container never has the opportunity to supply the dependencies.  Try using `Resolve`:

```
private static ITranslationService _translationService = 
                    container.Resolve<SSPResourceManagerWrapper>()._translation;
```

or even better:

```
private static ITranslationService _translationService = 
                    container.Resolve<ITranslationService>();
```

Comment: I don't have access to container object in the SSPResourceManagerclass. container object is used in global.asax. resolve centrally. I tried using contructor injection instead. passing in ITranslationService to SSPResourceManager,. i'll update the post question

Comment: Yes it is a difficult spot.  You are trying to initialize a global variable from the container and for that you need global variable access to the container.  IoC containers work best when resolving non-global dependency graphs.  If you do not want to expose the container itself, then you can try using the [global service locator exposed by Unity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664535%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx): `EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<ITranslationService>()`